# A complicated combinatoric equation for Stirling number

Tags: combinatorics

I'm self studying combinatoric this semester. But the text is hard to follow and I can only understand the basic material, but not knowing how to prove the intermediate level exercise. I want to know how to prove $$s(n,k)=\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}(-1)^j{n-1+j\choose n-k+j}{2n-k\choose n-k-j}S(n-k+j,j)$$ Any hint or detail solution is welcome.

Comment: This appears as eq (24) on the Wolfram site for Stirling numbers of the second kind.  A reference is given.  Have you tried it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from

$$(-1)^{n+k} {n\brack k} =
\sum_{j=0}^{n-k} (-1)^j {n-1+j\choose n-k+j} 
{2n-k\choose n-k-j} {n-k+j\brace j}$$

we introduce  the EGF for Stirling  numbers of the second  kind on the
RHS, getting

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-k} (-1)^j {n-1+j\choose n-k+j} 
{2n-k\choose n-k-j} (n-k+j)! [z^{n-k+j}] \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^j}{j!}
\\ = (n-k)! [z^{n-k}] \sum_{j=0}^{n-k} (-1)^j {n-1+j\choose n-k+j} 
{2n-k\choose n-k-j} {n-k+j\choose j} \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^j}{z^j}.$$

Now

$${n-1+j\choose n-k+j}  {n-k+j\choose j}
= \frac{(n-1+j)!}{(k-1)! \times j! \times (n-k)!}
= {n-1\choose k-1} {n-1+j\choose n-1}$$

and we find

$$\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!}
[z^{n-k}] \sum_{j=0}^{n-k} (-1)^j {n-1+j\choose n-1}
{2n-k\choose n-k-j} \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^j}{z^j}
\\ = \frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!}
[z^{n-k}] \sum_{j=0}^{n-k} (-1)^j {n-1+j\choose n-1}
\frac{(\exp(z)-1)^j}{z^j} [w^{n-k-j}] (1+w)^{2n-k}
\\ = \frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!} [w^{n-k}] (1+w)^{2n-k}
[z^{n-k}] \sum_{j=0}^{n-k} (-1)^j {n-1+j\choose n-1}
\frac{(\exp(z)-1)^j}{z^j} w^j.$$

Note  that  there is  no  contribution  to the  coefficient  extractor
$[w^{n-k}]$ when $j\gt n-k$, so we may write

$$\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!} [w^{n-k}] (1+w)^{2n-k}
[z^{n-k}] \sum_{j\ge 0} (-1)^j {n-1+j\choose n-1}
\frac{(\exp(z)-1)^j}{z^j} w^j
\\ = \frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!} [w^{n-k}] (1+w)^{2n-k}
[z^{n-k}] \frac{1}{(1+w(\exp(z)-1)/z)^n}
\\ = \frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!} [w^{n-k}] (1+w)^{2n-k}
[z^{n-k}] \frac{z^n/(\exp(z)-1)^n}{(w+z/(\exp(z)-1))^n}.$$

Working with

$$\mathrm{Res}_{w=0} 
\frac{1}{w^{n-k+1}} (1+w)^{2n-k} \frac{1}{(w-C)^n}$$

we compute the residues  at $C$ and at infinity in  order to apply the
fact that they must sum to zero. Starting with the first we require
(Leibniz rule)

$$\frac{1}{(n-1)!} 
\left(\frac{1}{w^{n-k+1}} (1+w)^{2n-k}\right)^{(n-1)}
\\ = \frac{1}{(n-1)!}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose q} 
\frac{(n-k+q)!}{(n-k)!} (-1)^q \frac{1}{w^{n-k+1+q}} \\ \times
\frac{(2n-k)!}{(2n-k-(n-1-q))!} (1+w)^{2n-k-(n-1-q)}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^{n-1}
{n-k+q\choose q} (-1)^q \frac{1}{w^{n-k+1+q}}
{2n-k\choose n-1-q} (1+w)^{n-k+1+q}
\\ = \left(\frac{1+w}{w}\right)^{n-k+1}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-1}
{n-k+q\choose q} (-1)^q 
{2n-k\choose n-1-q} \left(\frac{1+w}{w}\right)^{q}.$$

We have two important observations, the first is that

$$\frac{z^n}{(\exp(z)-1)^n} = 1+\cdots$$

i.e. no pole at zero and that

$$\left.\frac{1+w}{w}\right|_{w=-z/(\exp(z)-1)}
= \frac{1+z-\exp(z)}{z} = -\frac{1}{2} z + \cdots.$$

Hence on substituting into the coefficient extractor on $[z^{n-k}]$
we get for all sum terms

$$[z^{n-k}] (1+\cdots) \left(-\frac{1}{2} z + \cdots\right)^{n-k+1}
\times \left(-\frac{1}{2} z + \cdots\right)^q = 0,$$

i.e.  due to  the  middle term  there is  zero  contribution from  the
residue at  $w=-z/(\exp(z)-1).$ Returning  to the main  computation we
get for the residue at infinity

$$\mathrm{Res}_{w=\infty} 
\frac{1}{w^{n-k+1}} (1+w)^{2n-k} \frac{1}{(w-C)^n}
\\ = - \mathrm{Res}_{w=0} \frac{1}{w^2} 
w^{n-k+1} (1+1/w)^{2n-k} \frac{1}{(1/w-C)^n}
\\ = - \mathrm{Res}_{w=0} \frac{1}{w^2} 
w^{2n-k+1} \frac{(1+w)^{2n-k}}{w^{2n-k}} \frac{1}{(1-Cw)^n}
\\ = - \mathrm{Res}_{w=0} \frac{1}{w}
(1+w)^{2n-k} \frac{1}{(1-Cw)^n} = -1.$$

On flipping the  sign and substituting into  the coefficient extractor
on $z$ we get

$$\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!}
[z^{n-k}] \frac{z^n}{(\exp(z)-1)^n}
\\ = \frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!}
\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^{n-k+1}} \frac{z^n}{(\exp(z)-1)^n}.$$

Summing we get for the OGF

$$\sum_{k=1}^n x^k \frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!}
\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{z^{k-1}}{(\exp(z)-1)^n}
\\ = x (n-1)! \times \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{(\exp(z)-1)^n}
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x^{k-1} z^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}
\\ = x (n-1)! \times 
\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{\exp(xz)}{(\exp(z)-1)^n}.$$

Now we evaluate the residue for $1\le x\le n$ an integer. We have

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{\exp(xz)}{(\exp(z)-1)^n}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{\exp(xz)}{(\exp(z)-1)^n} \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{\exp((x-1)z)}{(\exp(z)-1)^n} \exp(z) \; dz
$$

and putting $\exp(z) = w$ so that $\exp(z) \; dz = dw$ we obtain

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\gamma} \frac{w^{x-1}}{(w-1)^n} \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\gamma} \frac{1}{(w-1)^n} 
\sum_{q=0}^{x-1} {x-1\choose q} (w-1)^q\; dw.$$

This is zero when $x-1\lt n-1$ or $x\lt n$ and it is one when $x=n.$
By construction the residue is a polynomial in $x$ of degree $n-1.$ We have
the $n-1$ roots, they are at $x=1,2,\ldots,n-1$ so we know it is

$$Q (x-1)(x-2)\times\cdots\times (x-(n-1)).$$

But we also know that at $x=n$ it evaluates to one, so we must have
$$Q (n-1)(n-2)\times\cdots\times 1 = 1$$ or $Q=1/(n-1)!.$ Restoring
the two terms in front we finally obtain

$$x(n-1)! \times 
\frac{1}{(n-1)!} (x-1)(x-2)\times\cdots\times (x-(n-1))
\\ = x(x-1)(x-2)\times\cdots \times (x-(n-1))
= \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{n+k} {n\brack k} x^k$$

which is  precisely the Stirling  number OGF,  first kind, and  we are
done.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but a long comment.

Nice proof, Marko Riedel. I would add that you can get to the end a little faster starting from 'On flipping the sign...' Use the Norlund poly to conclude
$$[z^{n-k}]\Big(\frac{z}{e^z-1}\Big)^n = [z^{n-k}]\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{z^m}{m!}B_m^{(n)}(0)=\frac{B_{n-k}^{(n)}(0)}{(n-k)!}.$$

Then use the known fact that
$$   \begin{bmatrix} n \\ k \\ \end{bmatrix} = \frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!} \,\frac{B_{n-k}^{(n)}(0)}{(n-k)!} $$